# Mongo Query to find documents where array element contains two specific values

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb, mongoose

Trying to create a Mongo Query, using Mongoose for my Node.js project.

My Data looks similar to the sample provided below.

Need help in creating a Query to find documents containing `warehouse = A` with `qty greater than 10` and `warehouse = B`. Irrespective of whether other elements in `instock` array exist.

```
[
  {
    item: 'journal',
    instock: [
      { warehouse: 'A', qty: 5 },
      { warehouse: 'C', qty: 15 }
    ]
  },
  {
    item: 'planner',
    instock: [
      { warehouse: 'A', qty: 1 },
      { warehouse: 'B', qty: 5 }
    ]
  },
  {
    item: 'planner',
    instock: [
      { warehouse: 'A', qty: 40 },
      { warehouse: 'B', qty: 5 }
    ]
  },
  {
    item: 'postcard',
    in stock: [
      { warehouse: 'A', qty: 15 },
      { warehouse: 'B', qty: 15 },
      { warehouse: 'C', qty: 35 }
    ]
  }
]
```

### Expected result.

```
[{
    item: 'planner',
    instock: [
      { warehouse: 'A', qty: 40 },
      { warehouse: 'B', qty: 5 }
    ]
  },
  {
    item: 'postcard',
    instock: [
      { warehouse: 'A', qty: 15 },
      { warehouse: 'B', qty: 15 },
      { warehouse: 'C', qty: 35 }
    ]
  }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.collection.find({
  $and: [
    {
      instock: {
        "$elemMatch": {
          warehouse: "A",
          qty: {$gt: 10},
        }
      }
    },
    {
      instock: {
        "$elemMatch": {
          warehouse: "B"
        }
      }
    },
  ]
})
```

this query will find elements that have a and qty > 10 and b element without qty check

Comment: The second condition in the `$and` is a [Single Query Condition](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#single-query-condition): If you specify only a single `<query>` condition in the 
`$elemMatch` expression, and are not using the `$not` or `$ne` operators inside of `$elemMatch`, `$elemMatch` can be omitted. So it can be `{ "instock.warehouse": "B"}`.